# How to find commit of first release in Git repository

Tags: git, github, github-api, google-bigquery

I am trying to analyze influences, e.g. commit rate, on the duration until the first release of a software repositories on github.

I found out that using the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) is not a good idea as most of the repository do not use this functionality of github.

My second idea was to use the information in tags, but it seems that tags are not named consistently through different repositories, e.g. you could have following tags:

- v1.0
- v.1.0.1
- Release 1.0
- Release 1.0.1
- 1.0
- 1.0.1
- 1.0.0.10
- etc.

Of course I could use regular expression to filter out relevant tags, but I wonder if there is a more convinient way to get releases, especially the first release of a repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be a better way. Paging @torek

```
for x in `git tag`; do
  TAG=`git log -n1 --pretty="%cd %h" --date=iso refs/tags/$x`
  LIST=`echo -e "${TAG}\n${LIST}"
done
echo "${LIST}" | sort -M --reverse | uniq | tail -n1 | awk '{print $4}'| xargs git describe --tags
```

Comment: `sort -M` seems to be month-name-based sort; not sure what you intend to do with that, since `--date=iso` produces `yyyy-mm-dd` dates. In general I'm not sure what to make of the OP's question though. Given tags spelled `abc` and `xyz`, which one is the first *release?* Is either one a release at all? Given tags spelled `v0.9` and `v1.0`, the first *release* is probably `v1.0`, though the commit date or tag date on `v0.9` is probably earlier than that on `v1.0`, etc.

Comment: I went for tag date. Even though the date string is out of order it seemed to work. Wasn't sure if you had any better ideas.

Comment: Valuable input for sure. I was going for a similar approach, analyzing the tags and sorting them by date. But given the question of @torek, e.g. for Python packages often version numbers like `0.22.0` or similar can be seen. They have there own rules on how to count through release. So it seems, that there is no consistent way.